# Log4r. How to write two log files from one logger.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, log4r

I used the following tutorial to configure logging in my rails application http://blog.mmlac.com/log4r-for-rails/

log4r.yml

```
log4r_config:
  pre_config:
    custom_levels:
    - DEBUG
    - PARAMS
    - INFO
    - WARN
    - ERROR
    - EXCEPTION
    - FATAL
  # define all loggers ...
  loggers:
    - name          : rails
      level         : DEBUG
      trace         : 'false'
      outputters    :
      - console
      - railsfiledebug

    - name          : mysql
      level         : DEBUG
      trace         : 'false'
      outputters    :
      - console
      - railsfile


  # define all outputters (incl. formatters)
  outputters:
  - type: StdoutOutputter
    name: console
    formatter:
      date_pattern: '%H:%M:%S'
      pattern     : '%d %l: %m'
      type        : PatternFormatter

  - type: FileOutputter
    name: railsfile
    filename: "log/cryptoserver_#{ENV}.log" # notice the file extension is needed!
    trunc: false
    formatter:
      date_pattern: '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S.%L %z'
      pattern     : '[#{EC2_INSTANCE}][%p][#{APPNAME}]|[RAILS][%d][%l]: %m '
      type        : PatternFormatter
```

In my application.rb:

```
Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger['rails']
```

How can I configure the logger to make two separate files:

1) debug.log where logged all messages with priority DEBUG and less.

2) app.log where presents the same messages as in debug.log except DEBUG and PARAMS

So

```
Rails.logger.info 'this should go in two log files'
Rails.logger.debug 'this should go in debug.log only'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I can use two FileOutputters with different error levels

```
- type: FileOutputter
    name: railsfile
    level: INFO
    filename: "log/cryptoserver_#{ENV}.log" # notice the file extension is needed!
    trunc: false
    formatter:
      date_pattern: '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S.%L %z'
      pattern     : '[#{EC2_INSTANCE}][%p][#{APPNAME}]|[RAILS][%d][%l]: %m '
      type        : PatternFormatter

  - type: FileOutputter
    name: railsfiledebug
    level: DEBUG
    filename: "log/debug_#{ENV}.log" # notice the file extension is needed!
    trunc: false
    formatter:
      date_pattern: '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S.%L %z'
      pattern     : '[#{EC2_INSTANCE}][%p][#{APPNAME}]|[RAILS][%d][%l]: %m '
      type        : PatternFormatter
```